# Nextflow doesn't use the right service account to deploy workflows to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nextflow

We're trying to use nextflow on a k8s namespace other than our default, the namespace we're using is `nextflownamespace`. We've created our PVC and ensured the default service account has an admin rolebinding. We're getting an error that nextflow can't access the PVC:

```
"message": "persistentvolumeclaims \"my-nextflow-pvc\" is forbidden: 
User \"system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:default\" cannot get resource 
\"persistentvolumeclaims\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"nextflownamespace\"",
```

In that error we see that `system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:default` is incorrectly pointing to our default namespace, `mynamespace`, not `nextflownamespace` which we created for nextflow use.

We tried adding `debug.yaml = true` to our `nextflow.config` but couldn't find the YAML it submits to k8s to validate the error. Our config file looks like this:

```
profiles {
  standard { 
    k8s {
          executor = "k8s"
          namespace = "nextflownamespace"
          cpus = 1
          memory = 1.GB
          debug.yaml = true
        }
    aws{ 
          endpoint = "https://s3.nautilus.optiputer.net"
       }
  }
```

We did verify that when we change the namespace to another arbitrary value the error message used the new arbitrary namespace, but the service account name continued to point to the users default namespace erroneously.

We've tried every variant of `profiles.standard.k8s.serviceAccount = "system:serviceaccount:nextflownamespace:default"` that we could think of but didn't get any change with those attempts.

Comment: I wonder if something silly is happening using a nested profile? I.e. what happens when your remove the 'standard' layer from your [config profile](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-profiles) then setting `profiles.k8s.serviceAccount = "system:serviceaccount:nextflownamespace:default"`?

Comment: @Steve it looks like that did it! We moved past that to another error. We just removed standard from the profiles and removed `--profile` from the command line. If you can copy that into an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Awsome - I have zero experience with Kubernetes so am really glad I could help with this one! I hope the answer below is ok. Did you also need to add a value for the 'serviceAccount' setting? I would still expect `-profile k8s` on the command line, though (note the single vs double dash/hyphen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to avoid using nested [config profiles](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-profiles) with Nextflow. I would either remove the 'standard' layer from your profile or just make 'standard' a separate profile:

```
profiles {

    standard {
      process.executor = 'local'
    }

    k8s {
        executor = "k8s"
        namespace = "nextflownamespace"
        cpus = 1
        memory = 1.GB
        debug.yaml = true
    }

    aws{ 
        endpoint = "https://s3.nautilus.optiputer.net"
    }
}
```